# PyQt5 - Items added to custom layout have different size if they are added after QWidget.show() has been called

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt

I am trying to add items to a FlowLayout dynamically and I have stumbled upon a bug that is really annoying.

When I add items before calling the show() method of the parent widget, they do not have the same dimensions as when they are added after calling the show() method:

[image]

All the buttons should have the same size except for the width which obviously is dependent on the text lenght.

Here's the code I used to achieve this (unwanted) result.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class FlowLayout(QLayout):
    def __init__(self, orientation=Qt.Horizontal, parent=None, margin=0, spacing=-1):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.orientation = orientation

        if parent is not None:
            self.setContentsMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)

        self.setSpacing(spacing)

        self.itemList = []

    def __del__(self):
        item = self.takeAt(0)
        while item:
            item = self.takeAt(0)

    def addItem(self, item):
        self.itemList.append(item)

    def count(self):
        return len(self.itemList)

    def itemAt(self, index):
        if index >= 0 and index < len(self.itemList):
            return self.itemList[index]

        return None

    def takeAt(self, index):
        if index >= 0 and index < len(self.itemList):
            return self.itemList.pop(index)

        return None

    def expandingDirections(self):
        return Qt.Orientations(Qt.Orientation(0))

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return self.orientation == Qt.Horizontal

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        return self.doLayout(QRect(0, 0, width, 0), True)

    def hasWidthForHeight(self):
        return self.orientation == Qt.Vertical

    def widthForHeight(self, height):
        return self.doLayout(QRect(0, 0, 0, height), True)

    def setGeometry(self, rect):
        super().setGeometry(rect)
        self.doLayout(rect, False)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSize()

    def minimumSize(self):
        size = QSize()

        for item in self.itemList:
            size = size.expandedTo(item.minimumSize())

        margin, _, _, _ = self.getContentsMargins()

        size += QSize(2 * margin, 2 * margin)
        return size

    def doLayout(self, rect, testOnly):
        x = rect.x()
        y = rect.y()
        lineHeight = columnWidth = heightForWidth = 0

        for item in self.itemList:
            wid = item.widget()
            spaceX = self.spacing() + wid.style().layoutSpacing(QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Horizontal)
            spaceY = self.spacing() + wid.style().layoutSpacing(QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Vertical)
            if self.orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                nextX = x + item.sizeHint().width() + spaceX
                if nextX - spaceX > rect.right() and lineHeight > 0:
                    x = rect.x()
                    y = y + lineHeight + spaceY
                    nextX = x + item.sizeHint().width() + spaceX
                    lineHeight = 0

                if not testOnly:
                    item.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

                x = nextX
                lineHeight = max(lineHeight, item.sizeHint().height())
            else:
                nextY = y + item.sizeHint().height() + spaceY
                if nextY - spaceY > rect.bottom() and columnWidth > 0:
                    x = x + columnWidth + spaceX
                    y = rect.y()
                    nextY = y + item.sizeHint().height() + spaceY
                    columnWidth = 0

                heightForWidth += item.sizeHint().height() + spaceY
                if not testOnly:
                    item.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

                y = nextY
                columnWidth = max(columnWidth, item.sizeHint().width())

        if self.orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return y + lineHeight - rect.y()
        else:
            return heightForWidth - rect.y()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    class Window(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

            #flowLayout = FlowLayout(orientation=Qt.Horizontal)
            self.flowLayout = FlowLayout(orientation=Qt.Vertical)

            self.setLayout(self.flowLayout)

            self.setWindowTitle("Flow Layout")
        def addItems(self):
            self.flowLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Short"))
            self.flowLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Longer"))
            self.flowLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Different text"))
            self.flowLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("More text"))
            self.flowLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Even longer button text"))

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = Window()

    mainWin.addItems() #Size is correct
    mainWin.show()
    mainWin.addItems() # Size is not correct (items are too big)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to avoid this behavior ?

**Edit** : It seems that the issues is coming from Qt's framework when using Windows 11 and two displays.

With the same code:

- The issue doesn't happen when only one screen is active
- The issue only happen on the secondary screen when using two different displays.

Comment: Questions should always be self-contained, and not rely on external resources (especially repositories, since their contents can change). Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Done, thank you.

I've experimented a bit with a simpler code, and I think I understand why my FlowLayout isn't working, items added AFTER calling the parent widget's show() method are way too big for some reason...

Comment: Note that Qt has no support for "width for height".

Answer (score 0):

`self.itemList` contains `QWidgetItem`s not widgets, so when you call `item.sizeHint()` it does not return widgets' size hint, it returns something else (need more digging to understand). You can verify that by adding this code to the top of `doLayout` function:

```py
for i,item in enumerate(self.itemList):
    widget = item.widget()
    print("{} item size hint {} widget size hint {}".format(i, item.sizeHint(), widget.sizeHint()))
print("")
```

It prints

```
0 item size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23) widget size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23)
1 item size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23) widget size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23)
2 item size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23) widget size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23)
3 item size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23) widget size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23)
4 item size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(123, 23) widget size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(123, 23)
5 item size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23) widget size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23)
6 item size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize() widget size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23)
7 item size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize() widget size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23)
8 item size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize() widget size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23)
9 item size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize() widget size hint PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(123, 23)
```

`PyQt5.QtCore.QSize()` represents 0x0 size here

But strangely enough `QWidgetItem.sizeHint()` returns empty size only few times and then falls back to returning `QWidget.sizeHint()`

So obvious fix would be repacing `item.sizeHint()` everywhere in code with something like

```
widget = item.widget()
itemOrWidget = item if widget is None else widget 
itemOrWidget.sizeHint()
```

or with function call

```
def sizeHint(item):
    widget = item.widget()
    if widget:
        return widget.sizeHint()
    return item.sizeHint()
```

Also, I have `PyQt5-5.12.3` and I cannot reproduce behaviour on attached image, code just works as it is, all buttons have expected size, the only issue is that layout reports zero size hint and window got shrinked to minimum size, which I fixed with `mainWin.resize(QSize(400, 400))`

Comment: The empty size hint of the item is probably caused by the delayed layout which updates the hint *later* in the event loop (the widget/layout item needs to call its internal geometry updates, which could cause recursion if called instantly).

Comment: I've made some "progress" and it seems to be a bug either on Qt or PyQt side when using Windows 11 and two displays.

With the same code:

1) The issue doesn't happen when only one screen is active
2) The issue only happen on the secondary screen when using two different displays

This is annoying, but at least the bug isn't on my side ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issues is coming from PyQt5.

With the same code:

- The issue doesn't happen when only one screen is active.
- The issue only happen on the secondary screen when using two different displays.

Migrating the code to PyQt6 resolve the issue, everything behaves as expected.